# Associate Class With the Vectorizing Words

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tf-idf

I'm doing Tensorflow Classification on a list of tweets and their Classes, the problem is after splitting the tweet into words then vectorizing it using TF-IDF, the length of words are bigger than the length of the classes.

(DataFrame "example" imported from CSV):

```
   Class                 Tweet
0   1   ضميان قرب شفتك سيد الخود اخاف اموت فراق ما ابت...
1   5   بعد مرور اسبوع عاد صاحب المزرعه ليقول للديك : ...
2   1   انا لو ابتل على الطبخ والموالح ابرك لي من الحل...
3   1   انا اكثر انسان يصلح يقدم محاضرات عن "كيف تيأس ...
4   1   الاغنيه تخلص بس لمن اغنيها انا لا، ابتل اعيد و...
5   1   اللهم أهدني سُقيا من سمائك أبتل بها ولا أزل.
```

(converting words to TF-IDF code):

```
mess = "

def text_cleaning(mess):
    delpunc = [c for c in mess if c not in string.punctuation]
    delpunc = ''.join(delpunc)
    return [word for word in delpunc.split() if word.lower() not in 
    stopwords]

# ==== Vectorization TF ====
bagow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_cleaning).fit(tweet['Tweet'][:10])
tweet_bagow = bagow_transformer.transform(tweet['Tweet'][:10])

# ==== Vectorization TF-IDF =====
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(tweet_bagow)
tweet_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(tweet_bagow)
```

If I `print(tweet_tfidf)` the output:

> Classify the output:
>
> ( Tweet ID, Word ID )  Word Weight

```
  (0, 141)  0.35476981351536396      
  (0, 91)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 84)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 82)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 77)   0.35476981351536396      
  (0, 76)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 69)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 36)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 25)   0.3015867532506004       
  (0, 11)   0.3015867532506004      
  (0, 5)    0.14366697931897693      
  (1, 142)  0.335452510590434        
  (1, 129)  0.335452510590434        
  (1, 125)  0.335452510590434       
  (1, 103)  0.2851652809360297       
  (1, 42)   0.335452510590434        
  (1, 41)   0.335452510590434        
  (1, 18)   0.335452510590434        
  (1, 14)   0.335452510590434        
  (1, 6)    0.335452510590434        
  (1, 5)    0.13584427723416684      
  (2, 119)  0.2504289625926897
  (2, 118)  0.2504289625926897
  (2, 117)  0.2504289625926897
  (2, 93)   0.2504289625926897
  : :
  (8, 62)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 55)   0.3541812544483204
  (8, 51)   0.3541812544483204
  (8, 48)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 43)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 40)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 39)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 37)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 35)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 32)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 24)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 21)   0.1770906272241602
  (8, 5)    0.07171431872090847
  (9, 123)  0.29928865657458936
  (9, 114)  0.29928865657458936
  (9, 105)  0.29928865657458936
  (9, 100)  0.29928865657458936
  (9, 89)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 59)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 49)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 20)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 17)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 15)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 10)   0.29928865657458936
  (9, 5)    0.12119942451824135
```

the `type(tweet_tfidf)` is:

```
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

In the **tensorflow**, you should have **training text and training class** .. i have the training text and i don't have the training class. 
I want to have a DataFrame with the Word Weight associated with the correct class, like this for example:

> ( Tweet ID, Word ID ) ... Word Weight ... Class

```
  (0, 141)  0.35476981351536396      1
  (0, 91)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 84)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 82)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 77)   0.35476981351536396      1
  (0, 76)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 69)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 36)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 25)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 11)   0.3015867532506004       1
  (0, 5)    0.14366697931897693      1
  (1, 142)  0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 129)  0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 125)  0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 103)  0.2851652809360297       5
  (1, 42)   0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 41)   0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 18)   0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 14)   0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 6)    0.335452510590434        5
  (1, 5)    0.13584427723416684      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs a little manipulation. You need -

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
import string
import numpy as np

tweet = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
mess = ''
stopwords = []

def text_cleaning(mess):
    delpunc = [c for c in mess if c not in string.punctuation]
    delpunc = ''.join(delpunc)
    return [word for word in delpunc.split() if word.lower() not in 
    stopwords]

# ==== Vectorization TF ====
bagow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_cleaning).fit(tweet['Tweet'][:10])
tweet_bagow = bagow_transformer.transform(tweet['Tweet'][:10])

# ==== Vectorization TF-IDF =====
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(tweet_bagow)
tweet_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(tweet_bagow)

ind_mapping = dict(zip(tweet.index, tweet.Class))
print(ind_mapping)

import scipy
I, J, V = scipy.sparse.find(tweet_tfidf)
print(pd.DataFrame([ [i,j,v,ind_mapping[i]] for i,j,v in zip(I,J,V)], columns=['row_index', 'column_index', 'tf_idf', 'class']))
```

**Output**

```
     row_index  column_index    tf_idf  class
0           5             0  0.339570      1
1           5             1  0.339570      1
2           5             2  0.339570      1
3           0             3  0.333333      1
4           2             4  0.283865      1
5           4             4  0.268247      1
6           2             5  0.346171      1
7           0             6  0.333333      1
8           1             7  0.353553      5
9           4             8  0.327125      1
10          4             9  0.327125      1
11          3            10  0.339570      1
12          4            11  0.327125      1
13          2            12  0.346171      1
14          0            13  0.333333      1
15          2            14  0.346171      1
16          5            15  0.339570      1
17          1            16  0.353553      5
18          0            17  0.333333      1
19          3            18  0.278453      1
20          4            18  0.268247      1
21          3            19  0.339570      1
22          4            20  0.327125      1
23          1            21  0.353553      5
24          5            22  0.339570      1
25          4            23  0.327125      1
26          3            24  0.339570      1
27          5            25  0.339570      1
28          0            26  0.333333      1
29          5            27  0.339570      1
30          0            28  0.333333      1
31          1            29  0.353553      5
32          1            30  0.353553      5
33          2            31  0.346171      1
34          3            32  0.339570      1
35          0            33  0.333333      1
36          0            34  0.333333      1
37          3            35  0.339570      1
38          4            36  0.327125      1
39          1            37  0.353553      5
40          4            38  0.327125      1
41          2            39  0.346171      1
42          2            40  0.346171      1
43          1            41  0.353553      5
44          0            42  0.333333      1
45          3            43  0.339570      1
46          1            44  0.353553      5
47          2            45  0.283865      1
48          5            45  0.278453      1
49          4            46  0.327125      1
50          2            47  0.346171      1
51          5            48  0.339570      1
52          3            49  0.339570      1
53          3            50  0.339570      1
```

**Explanation**

Create a mapping of the indices and the classes -

```
ind_mapping = dict(zip(tweet.index, tweet.Class))
```

Get `row_index`, `column_index` and the `tf_idf` values -

```
import scipy
I, J, V = scipy.sparse.find(tweet_tfidf)
```

Convert into a `dataframe` the values and mappings -

```
print(pd.DataFrame([ [i,j,v,ind_mapping[i]] for i,j,v in zip(I,J,V)], columns=['row_index', 'column_index', 'tf_idf', 'class']))
```

Comment: **You are the best, Thank you so much sir!**